# Passing data to a view's controller via $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

I have a view, `/views/chart.html` that is linked to the controller `SinglechartCtrl` and I want to pass some data to the controller to allow it to start drawing the correct content. The context is that there will be lots of pages with very similar charts on and it seems stupid to be creating new views/controllers for each of these when they will function very similarly.

I have a service, `chartManifest` which contains a JSON object which maps out the chart details, the API endpoint to gather data from, the category structure etc, and I wish to insert some link to this data via `$routeProvider`. As pseudo code:

```
...
  .when('/ios/installs', {
    templateUrl: 'views/chart.html',
    controller: 'SinglechartCtrl'.
    metaData: {
      category: 'ios',
      name: 'installs
    }
  })
...
```

The `chartManifest` service would then be queried using this meta data passed to `SinglechartCtrl` and we could draw the chart from there. An extract of the object in the `chartManifest` service is:

```
$scope.charts = {
    "ios": {
        "installs": {
            "type": "line",
            "endpoint": "api/thing"
        },
        "activeusers": {
            "type": "bar",
            "endpoint": "api/thing"
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate this may be a totally incorrect way of dealing with this (I'm very new to Angular), but it seems this is far closer to the solution than a fresh view/controller for each very similar chart. Obviously `metaData` is not a real thing but hopefully this gets across the idea of what I'm trying to achieve. One thought involved using the `resolve` property on `$routeProvider.when()` but this is inserting dependencies, not just small amounts of data.

Comment: Are you familiar with [$routeParams](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)? (see details for "path")

Comment: yes, excellent. i should be able to get something out of that. thank you.